# How can I calibrate a Dell U2412M for 100% of Adobe RGB?

Tags: color-management, display-calibration, adobe-rgb

My in-warranty Dell U2412M monitor is wide gamut, and I've set it for Adobe RGB. Yet when I calibrate the monitor with a Spyder 4 by DataColor, I can only get 79% of the RGB color gamut. How can I achieve 100%? The Spyder is properly set for Adobe RGB.

Answer (score 7):

Carol, are you sure you have the U2414M? That's Dell's *medium* gamut variant of the monitor, covering about 75% of Adobe RGB. So I think that if that's the monitor you have, it's behaving as expected.

See [this review on TFT central](http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/reviews/dell_u2412m.htm) for details.

Dell's terminology here is unfortunately confusing, since previously the [U2413](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-u2413/pd) (with no *M*) was the wide-gamut variant, but now the new [2415](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=860-BBDY) (still no *M*) is also only standard gamut (albeit with a respectable 99% coverage of sRGB, similar to the U2414M). It looks like Dell is now using the term ***PremierColor*** for its wide-gamut displays — see [this list on their web site](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/ultrasharp-monitors).